# Workflow for using version control with automated backup/sync

Tags: backup, sync, version-control

I am currently working on several different projects.  I use Mercurial for version control (through BitBucket) and SpiderOak for automated backup.  I work on two machines, a desktop at home and a laptop when I'm out and about.  I have set SpiderOak to automatically synchronize my `/home` directories (which contains the various repositories for my projects) between the two machines.

Currently SpiderOak also synchronizes the `.hg` subfolder for each repository.  But I think this is causing problems.  I just committed and pushed a repository to BitBucket from my desktop.  I then started working on the project on my laptop after SpiderOak had synchronized the files, but without pulling and updating from BitBucket.  Then when I tried to commit and push from my laptop, I got the following error message:

```
abort: push creates new remote head 7f6bf2d3292b!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
```

On the other hand, I used to have SpiderOak just synchronize the project folders without synchronizing the `.hg` folders.  That caused problems when using Mercurial too.  For instance, if I'd work on a project on my desktop and create a new file, say `newfile.tex`, then that would be synchronized to the laptop via SpiderOak, and (on the desktop) I would add it to the Mercurial repository via `hg add newfile.tex`.  But since the `.hg` folder wasn't synced between the two machines, the repository on the laptop wouldn't know about `newfile.tex`, even though I had added it to the repository on the desktop.  I don't want to have to add the files to the repositories on both machines individually.

I see that this is somewhat rambly,   So the question boils down to the following:

1. Should I synchronize the `.hg` folders or not?
2. What workflow should I use to ensure that everything is properly synchronized and that Mercurial doesn't get mad at me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why sync your source code at all (using SpiderOak)?  I would just use your version-control (Mercurial) tools to do the syncing.  If you use your version-control tools, it will know about all file changes and it will behave correctly.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  Then I could just use SpiderOak to back my projects up without syncing the two machines, and anytime I was switching machines I would let the version control take care of syncing.

Comment: I'd vote your answer up but I can't even do that yet!